# Using Ruby regex gsub only once

Tags: ruby, regex, string

I have the following string.

```
melody = "F# G# A# B |A# G# F#   |A# B C# D# |C# B A#   |F#   F#   
         |F#   F#   |F#F#G#G#A#A#BB|A# G# F#   "
```

I want to convert `F#` to `f`, `G#` to `g` etc.

```
melody.gsub(/C#/, 'c').gsub(/D#/,'d').gsub(/F#/,'f').gsub(/G#/,'g').gsub(/A#/,'a')
```

The above gives a desired output. But I am wondering if I can use `gsub` only once.

```
"f g a B |a g f   |a B c d |c B a   |f   f   |f   f   |ffggaaBB|a g f   "
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`String#gsub`](http://ruby-doc.org/core/String.html#method-i-gsub) accepts an optional block: return value of the block is used as replacement string:

```
melody.gsub(/[CDFGA]#/) { |x| x[0].downcase }
# => "f g a B |a g f   |a B c d |c B a   |f   f   |f   f   |ffggaaBB|a g f   "
```

Comment: do lowercase conversion..while substituting.

Comment: Short and sweet! +1 :)

Comment: Can you do this without a block, using a back reference?

Comment: @CarySwoveland, No, I can't.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Here is the [answer](https://www.ruby-forum.com/topic/4457150), why not possible...

Comment: @Arup, thanks for the reference.  My use of the term "backreference" may have been wrong.  Please see my answer for what I had in mind.

Comment: ft, thanks for pointing out the problem with my answer, which I deleted. My reading of the reference given by @Arup suggested it would not work, but it did work in IRB.  It was an IRB "gotcha". `$1` was correctly set with an incorrect formulation, so that when I tried the answer I posted (without first reloading IRB), no exception was raised because `$1` had previously been assigned a value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use hash too.

```
melody.gsub(/[CDFGA]#/, {'C#' => 'c', 'D#' => 'd', 'F#' => 'f', 'G#' => 'g', 'A#' => 'a'})
```

Comment: I don't think this is the most efficient solution in this case, but it is useful for you to have shown how to do more general substitutions.

Comment: yes, it's not short, but more general if your substitution has no relation with the matching.